# Store Image id in a array on Android

Tags: android, arrays, android-layout

I want to store selected Image Id in a array from drawable

Suppose i have a image a like this

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
    R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
    R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
    R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
    R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
    R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
    R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
    R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
    R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
    R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
    R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
    R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
```

};

Now i want to create same array with the help of loop please suggest me how i can do it

Thanks In Advance

Comment: how would you know that you want to add these many item or you want to add whole drawable folder to array

Comment: Simply asking why you want to do it ?

Comment: i want to create selected drawable  image array with the help of loop

Comment: elaborate your question. why you want to do it? what output you need exactly?

Comment: What is problem then? Do you know about loop?

Comment: I think you cannot create a reference to resource name with a loop. Probably you want to create a macro to write that instead. **Edit:** Perhaps you can, by using `getResources().getIdentifier(name, defType, defPackage)`, though it's discouraged by Android itself.

Comment: problem is that i am not able to store Image Id in a array

Comment: Why not you are showing the code which u are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe like this

```
int []images_id = new int[10];
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                images_id[i] = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/"+"filename_"+i, null, getPackageName());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you intend to get resource IDs?

The Resources class has this method:

```
  public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```

getIdentifier returns the integer of the specified resource name, type & package.  But this is not recommended way as obtaining identifiers is a slow process.

eg: (for drawables)

```
  final int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Like this?

code

```
//This loads all Ids that you have in the array
Integer[] allImageIds = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.allimageids);

//This will now possibly filter the Ids
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
for (int i = 0; i < allImageIds.length; i++)
  if ( your condition )
    list.add( allImageIds[i] );
Integer[] mThumbIds = list.toArray();
```

arrays.xml

```
<integer-array>
  <item>@id/sample_2</item>
  <item>@id/sample_3</item>
  <item>@id/sample_4</item>
  <item>@id/sample_5</item>
  ...
</integer-array>
```

You cannot however enumerate the Ids themselves, they are constants and are not listed in any predefined arrays. Android Java runtime does not have any RTTI storage. If you need these Ids in a list, you have to place them there manually.

Comment: Seriously? That really isn't going to work.

Comment: for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
     list.add(R.drawable.p+i);
   Integer[] mThumbIds = list.toArray();    using like this but getting error

Comment: Why not? The question is pretty vague and he just doesn't know about ArrayList. This solution assumes he has his Ids generated on the fly. The above code is a minimal example how he can dynamically append data into his solution array.

Comment: @deep: you can't obtain Ids like that. You would need a fixed translation array, which you can create in XML resources. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#IntegerArray

Comment: "Why not? ....he just doesn't know about ArrayList." - No, he just doesn't understand that everything in the R.java class is an int and it's not possible to do things like `R.drawable.p+i` (see his comment above). Explain exactly your bit of code which says `list.add( (insert your image id here) );` would work in any way.

Comment: Yes, I got that from his comment. A fixed resource array should be able to fix that for him, but then I don't see why he'd still want to use the loop as loading that array would be faster...

Comment: You missed my point - explain how **"(insert your image id here)"** could possibly work in a `for loop`.

Comment: Integer[] allImageIds = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.allImageIds);  (insert your image id == allImageIds[i];